# Does DataForm exist in Silverlight 4, or only in Silverlight 3?

Tags: c#, silverlight, forms

Silverlight's `DataForm` seems great. I see a ton of documentation for it in SL3, but not so much in SL4.

This [tutorial](http://csharperimage.jeremylikness.com/2009/11/rich-data-forms-in-silverlight-4-beta.html) is about SL4, but has **way** more XAML than I'd like to write, particularly given that `DataForm` is supposed to do all that for you.

I've also been following along with this [video](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/videos/silverlight-videos/dataform-control/), but he loses me when he references the `System.Windows.Controls.Data.DataForm` assembly. For me, that doesn't work:

> Assembly
>   'System.Windows.Controls.Data.DataForm'
>   was not found. Verify that you are not
>   missing an assembly reference. Also,
>   verify that your project and all
>   referenced assemblies have been built.

Am I doing something wrong here? I can't find a `System.Windows.Controls.Data.DataForm` assembly to which to add a reference. Did it get moved from SL3 to SL4?

Frustratingly, I can't seem to find official `DataForm` documentation on MSDN.

**UPDATE**: I found a [list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645072%28v=VS.95%29.aspx#d) of controls on MSDN. It doesn't include `DataForm`. Does that mean it's gone?

**UPDATE 2**: I created two projects in Expression Blend, one in SL3 and the other in SL4. I can't find `DataForm` as a control for either. For shame.

Comment: Are you talking about DataForm from the Silverlight toolkit? http://silverlight.codeplex.com/

Comment: I believe so, but I'm not entirely certain. I'm pretty sure I downloaded all the latest Silverlight tools about a month ago, so shouldn't I have `DataForm` already?

Comment: That site says that `DataForm` is in the "Preview" quality band, which is odd, considering how much 6 month+ old documentation talks about it as if it were stable / publicly available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DataForm` still exists and its assembly is **System.Windows.Controls.Data.DataForm.Toolkit**.

Comment: Where would I have gone to look that up, aside from asking it on SO?

Comment: I can't find that assembly to add a reference to it. I have `System.Windows.Controls.Data`, and `System.Windows.Controls.Data.Input`, but no `System.Windows.Controls.Data.DataForm.Toolkit`